# Changing textfield font of UISearchBar also changes it's height

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am changing UISearchBar's UITextField font size:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
```

or

```
searchBar.searchTextField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17)
```

This is the same font size value as the default. But UISearchBar also changes its height. Looks like it's a little bit bigger than the default height value. How I can fix it?

Default UISearchBar height:
[image]
After font size change (pay attention that actual font size is the same as on screenshot above):
[image]

UPDATE:
I have a storyboard with UITabBarViewController in it. Then I have two UIViewControllers connected to UITabBarViewController. One of them is empty and another one contains UINavigationController with connected sample VIewController which is UITableViewController. Here is a sample code of test ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    private lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .black
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .light
        return searchController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "TEST"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your ViewController code. This error is not replicable with the information you gave. I tried this and the size stays the same, you may have done something extra for it to change.

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 added code sample in answer. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 the same issue if I place UISearchBar on UIViewController with all default properties, then in UIVIewController changing font of searchBar (even if not in UINavigationController): `searchBar.searchTextField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17)`

Comment: Are you testing on a iOS 14 device? or is it a lower version?

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 Latest iOS version (14.7.1) and latest Xcode
Also tested on iOS 14.3 - the same issue
Both in simulator and real device (iPhone)

Very strange situation..

Comment: Oh, well. The only difference is that I'm using Xcode 14.2. One solution could be, after changing the text size, setting the frame of the searchbar to the height desired. If you need code let me know to post an answer.